# Add a formula which references a cell from another workbook in OPEN XML sdk using C#

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on Open XML sdk 2.0 in C#.

I have two workbooks Book1, and Book2.
Lets say Book1 have a value 10 in its cell D1. Then book2 should have 10 in its cell A1.
Book1 is already created And I need to work on book2.

I am trying to create a workbook Book2 which the cell A1 references the cell D1 from Book1(Sheet1).
When ever the user changes D1 in Book1 then the Value A1 in book2 should also change once this is done.

I have this code so far

```
Row row2 = new Row()
        {
            RowIndex = 1U,
            Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>()
        };

// string formula= "Sum(B2,B5)"; // this one works 
String formula= "'C:\Workbooks\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1"; // this does not

Cell cell3 = new Cell() { CellReference = "A1" };
CellFormula formula = new CellFormula(formula);
cell3.Append(formula);

CellValue value = new CellValue();
value.Text = "0";
cell3.Append(value);

row2.Append(cell3);
```

Whenever I add the row to the workbook and save it says the book2 is corrupt if I use the formula below

```
formula= "'C:\Workbooks\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1"; // this does not
```

But If I use a simple formula as below it works.

```
formula= "Sum(B2,B5)"; // this one works
```

I am not sure how to add a formula which references a cell from another workbook in OPEN XML sdk using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Excel needs an external reference informing it of the existance of the other sheet. To do this you'll need to call the [`AddExternalRelationship`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562653%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method on your `WorkBookPart`:

```
workbookpart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath", 
        new System.Uri(@"C:\Workbooks\Book2.xlsx", UriKind.Absolute), "rId1");
```

If you unzip an Xlsx file that references another workbook and navigate to the `xl` folder you will see there is an `externalLinks` folder. This is the part that you need to create.

Here's a full code example that will work which I've adapted from [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

```
public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
{
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
        Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
        AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
            GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = "mySheet"
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    Row row2 = new Row()
        {
            RowIndex = 1U
        };

    //add your formula as per your question
    String formula = @"'C:\Workbooks\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$1";

    Cell cell3 = new Cell() { CellReference = "A1" };
    CellFormula cellFormula = new CellFormula(formula);
    cell3.Append(cellFormula);

    row2.Append(cell3);

    //add a relationship that points to the correct file
    workbookpart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath",
        new System.Uri(@"C:\Workbooks\Book2.xlsx", UriKind.Absolute), "rId1");

    sheetData.Append(row2);

    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi @petelids. Thanks for the effort in responding to my question. But your solution did not work form me I didnt see the resulting file any different than mine. the resulting excel file is still corrupted( It could be repaired upon opening but that is not what I wanted)  I called your function using CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(@"C:\\Workbooks\Book1.xlsx');

Comment: Hi @Amete - I assume `C:\Workbooks\Book2.xlsx` exists and `C:\Workbooks\Book1.xlsx` doesn't exist at the time you run it? The above code worked for me. When you say it's corrupted are you prompted to update the value from `Book2`? Does the value from `Book2` appear?

Comment: The value from book2 appeared in Book1 as expected. But my problem is when I try to oepn the excel file Book1.xlsx it gives me a warning which says the workbook is corrupted...and I have to repair it and open then it looks good. I don't want my users to see that warning. Did you not see a warning when you opened book1? What version of Open XML sdk are you using I am using 2.0 so that could be different than yours?

Comment: Did you copy the code above verbatim? I don't get a warning, just a prompt to update the value which I would expect.

Comment: Yes I did copy paste it as it is and get the warning("Excel found unreadable content do you want to recover the contents...etc"). what is your open xml version and excel version you use to open the file? that could be the difference we have.

Comment: @Amete - I've tried the code with OpenXml 2.0.5022.0 and 2.5.5631.0. Both open without any issues in Excel 2013. I will try to open them in 2007 when I'm at a machine with that installed.

Comment: @ petelids I tried to open the file in Excel 2013 and it does not show a warning which is good but the cell A-1 does not show the value of D-1 from Book2 but it shows #REF1 whichwhen I double click it shows me the actual formula and I had to hit enter to see the value.

Comment: Hi @Amete - I've got around to looking at this again. I'd put a spurious `Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>()` on the `Row` which meant it was invalid. Removing that should get rid of your corruption error (post updated). As for the `#REF1` - I don't think you can change this via the API as I think it's an Excel security setting. See [this article](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-external-content-in-Office-documents-10204ae0-0621-411f-b0d6-575b0847a795?CorrelationId=b7b1d975-73d0-4952-8075-9a4708690b72&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) for more details.